# $L_2$ is of first category in $L_1$ (Rudin Excercise 2.4b)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, baire-category

We mean here $L_2$, and $L_1$ the usual Lebesgue spaces on the unit-interval. It is excercise 2.4 from Rudin. There's several ways to show that $L_2$ is nowhere dense in $L_1$.

But in (b) they ask to show that

$$\Lambda_n(f)=\int fg_n \to 0 $$

where $g_n = n$ on $[0,n^{-3}]$ and 0 otherwise, holds for $L_2$ but not for all $L_1$.
Apparantly this implies that $L_2$ is of the first Category, but I dont know how. 
Second, I can show this holds for $L_2$ but I cant find a counterexample in $L_1$.

Theorem 2.7 in Rudin says:

Let $\Lambda_n:X\to Y$ a sequence of continuous linear mappings ($X,Y$ topological vector spaces)
If $C$ is the set of all $x\in X$ for which $\{\Lambda_n x\}$ is Cauchy in $Y$, and if $C$ is of the second Category, then $C=X$.

So if we find a $f\in L_1$ such that $\Lambda_n(f)$ is not Cauchy, then we proved that $L_2\subset C \subset L_1$ is of the first category. However I dont see why showing that $\Lambda_n(f)$ does not converge to 0 for some $f\in L_1$ is enough here.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest functions in $L_1 \setminus L_2$ are $f_\alpha \colon x \mapsto x^\alpha$ with $-1 < \alpha \leqslant -\frac12$.

Computing $\int fg_n$ for such an $f_\alpha$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int f_\alpha g_n &= n\int_0^{n^{-3}} x^\alpha\,dx \\
&= \frac{n}{1+\alpha}n^{-3(1+\alpha)}\\
&= \frac{n^{-2-3\alpha}}{1+\alpha}.
\end{align}$$

We see that the sequence of integrals does not converge to $0$ iff $-2-3\alpha \geqslant 0 \iff \alpha \leqslant -\frac23$.

Regarding the second part, choosing $-1 < \alpha < -\frac23$ gives an $f\in L_1$ with $\Lambda_n(f) \to \infty$, so $\Lambda_n(f)$ certainly is not a Cauchy sequence. Choosing $\alpha = -\frac23$ gives an $f\in L_1$ such that $\Lambda_n(f)$ is constant, hence a Cauchy sequence, but does not converge to $0$.

Now, *if* $L_2$ were of the second category in $L_1$, then the fact that $\Lambda_n(f) \to 0$ for all $f\in L_2$ would imply that $\Lambda_n(f) \to 0$ for all $f\in L_1$, by part $(b)$ of theorem 2.7. But picking $\alpha < -\frac23$ to get an $f\in L_1$ such that $\Lambda_n(f)$ is not a Cauchy sequence seems preferable, since it's more direct.

Comment: Ha! Thank you very much. You are quick.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Can you explain your proof? You show that $\Lambda_n(f)$ does not converge to $0$ for every $f \in L^1$. What does this have to do with finding a $f$ such that $\Lambda_n(f)$ is not a Cauchy sequence? And why do you write 'Choosing $\alpha = -\frac23$ gives an $f\in L_1$ such that $\Lambda_n(f)$ is constant, hence a Cauchy sequence, but does not converge to $0$.' Why do we need this?

And is the part 'Now, if...' necessary or are we already finished?

Comment: @maa There are two different arguments in the answer. The simple direct one, showing that for $-1 < \alpha < -\frac{2}{3}$ and $f(x) = x^{\alpha}$ the sequence $\Lambda_n(f)$ is unbounded, hence not a Cauchy sequence. At that point we're done, $C$ isn't all of $L^1$, therefore $C$ is of the first category in $L^1$. The other argument is more involved. If $\Lambda_n(f)$ were a Cauchy sequence for all $f \in L^1$, then $\Lambda \colon f \mapsto \lim \Lambda_n(f)$ would be a continuous linear functional on $L^1$ (that uses the fact that $L^1$ is complete [although strictly speaking weaker …

Comment: … assumptions suffice]). Since $L^2$ is dense in $L^1$ and $\Lambda_n(f) \to 0$ for all $f \in L^2$ it would necessarily be the case that $\Lambda = 0$, i.e. $\Lambda_n(f) \to 0$ for all $f \in L^1$. Thus it is enough to find one $f \in L^1$ such that $\Lambda_n(f)$ doesn't converge to $0$. Whether for that $f$ the sequence $\Lambda_n(f)$ converges to a nonzero number or not at all then doesn't matter, the conclusion $C \neq L^1$ follows. The "Now, if …" finishes the second argument. The first argument is complete at "… not a Cauchy sequence".

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I understood! The problem is that we only heard about Theorem 2.8 in lecture: If $\{\Lambda_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous linear mappings from an F-space $X$ into a tvs $Y$ and if $\Lambda x=\lim \Lambda_nx$ exists for every $x \in X$, then $\Lambda$ is continuous. Can I use this theorem (instead of theorem 2.7) to find a contradiction to the assumption that $L^2(0,1)$ is of 2nd category in $L^1(0,1)$? Otherwise I would just copy Theorem 2.7 and work with theorem 2.7 instead. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @maa It depends on what else you can use. But if 2.8 is the only part of the "2.5 and corollaries" you can use, I don't see an easy way. It follows easily from 2.5 (the family $\{\Lambda_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is equicontinuous on $L^2$, but not on $L^1$) or 2.7. From 2.6 or 2.8, you can only _easily_ get $L^2 \subsetneqq L^1$, for "first category" you'd need some gymnastics. Just proving 2.5 has good chances of being the simplest of such gymnastics.

Comment: For $f \in L^2$ the operators are bounded, so we have $L^2 \subseteq M^c=\cup_{n \in \mathbb N} M_n^c$. One can show that these $M_n^c$ are nowhere dense.
So if we had $L^2=\cup_{n \in \mathbb N} M_n^c$, I would be finished, but we have $L^2 \subseteq \cup_{n \in \mathbb N} M_n^c$ instead.
Maybe this somehow still helps? Otherwise I will study 2.5 or 2.7

Comment: @maa You are finished when you notice that every subset of a set of the first category is of the first category. That follows easily from the straightforward fact that every subset of a nowhere dense set is nowhere dense. I think you will have no difficulty proving these facts. If you do, you're welcome to ask for hints, a complete proof, or anything in between.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh thanks! I didn't even think about this. I thought I had to find a different way because I couldn't get equality in $L^2 \subseteq \cup M_n^c$